# Testing random output in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I've been digging into Ruby lately and am working on throwing something together to put to use what I'm learning.

I've got a Sinatra app that outputs a random quote.  I'd like to put some RSpec testing around this since that seems to be the right path to take.

For testing the class, I did something like this:

```
 it "prints a random line" do
     QuoteFile.any_instance.stub(:random).and_return(@quote.to_s)

     @quotefile.random.should == "Sample quote"
 end
```

So I've taken this and put it into a basic Sinatra app.  My RSpec file looks like this:

```
describe 'Quote App' do
    include Rack::Test::Methods

    def app
        Sinatra::Application
    end

    it "prints random quote" do

      get '/'
         ????
    end
end
```

My question is:  How do I stub out the random aspect in the "get '/'?

Thanks guys!

Comment: what about using tools like webmock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
QuoteFile.any_instance.stub(:random).and_return("This is a random quote")
```

in your Sinatra test and check for the output. Here's an example.

```
describe 'Quote App' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  it "prints random quote" do
    QuoteFile.any_instance.stub(:random).and_return("This is a random quote")
    get '/'
    last_response.body.should =~ /This is a random quote/
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh wow.. I guess I should have just tried the same code.  That worked.  Thanks a bunch!